# How to limit vuetify styles to vue app only

Tags: vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have vue3/vuetify app and somehow the app affects css globals. e.g. in the following example the button is not shown as a button but as a blue text only but I want vuetify to only change styles from my app and nothing else.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    html * {
      font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
      color: blue;
    }

    button {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="app"></div>

  <button> Stupuid Btn</button>
  <h1> Stupuid Btn</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

I disabled css reset in my main.scss  like this:

```scss
@use 'vuetify' with (
   /* disable css reset for vuetify */
   $utilities: 'false'
);
```

and included the main.scss in my main.ts like this

```js
//import 'vuetify/styles'; // removed since overwriting $utilities
import './main.scss';
```

so from my understanding I disabled the potentially global css scope affecting css-reset (like in https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/css-reset/) and had expected vuetify itself not to affect global css scope.

The css in question changing the style is from the generated index.css and reads:

```css
button, input, select, textarea {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-style: none;
}
```

Since I dont include other css like this it must come from vuetify. Any idea how I can limit vuetify to affect only my app and its children html-tags but nothing else?

Cheers
Tom